# Typescript, How to define custom types to interface field?

Tags: typescript

I have a global type as below:

```js
declare global {
    type ResponseData = {
        opcode: number;
        message: string;
        data?: <WILL-CHANGE-ON-EACH-CASE>;
    };
}
```

I want to put a custom type on `data` field in each specific returns.
For example:

```js
interface AppInformation {
    NAME: string;
    VERSION: string;
}

// What should I put on a return type???
export const getAppInfo = (): {...ResponseData, data: AppInformation } => {
    return apiResponse.success(200, CONFIG.APP);
};
```

What should I put on a return type of `getAppInfo`?
I leave something to get the idea of what I'm looking for.

Thanks beforehand,

Comment: Presumably you want `ResponseData` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) like [this (web IDE link)](https://tsplay.dev/w11GKw), but the example code here isn't a [mcve] so I'm not sure.  Please consider modifying your example code so that it demonstrates what you're doing when dropped into an IDE without dependencies on undeclared values or types.

Comment: @jcalz that was exactly what I was expecting!
Thanks, solved!

Answer (score 2):

You want `ResponseData` to be a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types), with a type parameter (such as) `T` that represents the type of the `data` property:

```
type ResponseData<T> = {
  opcode: number;
  message: string;
  data?: T
};
```

Then you can specify `T` when you want, to "plug in" a specific type like `AppInformation`:

```
interface AppInformation {
  NAME: string;
  VERSION: string;
}

const getAppInfo = (): ResponseData<AppInformation> => {
  return {
    opcode: 1, message: "msg", data: {
      NAME: "name", VERSION: "ver"
    }
  }
};
```

And the compiler will understand that the `data` (if present) will be of type `AppInformation`:

```
console.log(getAppInfo().data?.NAME.toUpperCase())
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEAiBDYWA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRRJgDGSAJhAFxQoCuAtgEYQATgG4aUHgnhYA5uyjxgggJYppo2sxxYA-BwJUAvqKorgQgGZYG0AIJgwASRTmkgnjiWpKYgHI2AsgCiHArKqupQAGqBMADKDgDyPiGKKmqGVFRMaMBQssB2js5IZFAAFACUHHCIqOjYuHiFTi5uHqgkpCTUtIIQwFyCKN60tPRMrBwAjAA04pIycgBEPPDSS3OauBw9o7R+QRxLKFgSG1Ex8UlHAG5CS2K0BmLPRplZdUgANhAAdF9IaRlfLNYqVX5bHS-A6BX7AJAAVXsQgAwlh0JUKkA)